# Need timestamps of each frame captured in AVCaptureSession on AVCam

Tags: iphone, avcapturesession, avcam, cmsamplebuffer

What I need, is to be able to edit AVCam so that I can store, access or view somehow the timestamps of each frame in a short video captured. After some research, I think it can be done but unsure how. I have seen in Xcode 'CMSampleBuffergetoutputsampletiminginfoarray' which sounds like it might help. Or perhaps by using, getpresentationtimestamp etc.

I don't know exactly which timestamp I need (PTS or DTS), I am going to film a fast moving object and would like the exact time elapsed between each frame.

Please help!